# Angular testing [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: STARTUP_CONFIG

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm having trouble getting my tests to run due to dependencies not beeing injected correctly.

The error I'm getting is defined in the title. I've included the actual test code, the app.js & index.html file from my solution.

The problem lies with the deferred bootstrap which I'm not fimiliar with as it was included by one of my colleagues. If I remove the "app.config(function (STARTUP_CONFIG..." from the app.js file then the test runs fine

How can I correctly inject the STARTUP_CONFIG in my test?

**test code**

```
..
..
describe("test description...", function () {

var app;
var mockupDataFactory;

beforeEach(module('Konstrukt'));

beforeEach(inject(function (STARTUP_CONFIG,BUDGETS,APPLICATIONS) {
    //failed attempt to inject STARTUP_CONFIG
}));

beforeEach(function () {
    app = angular.module("Konstrukt");
});

beforeEach(function () {
    mockupDataFactory = konstruktMockupData.getInstance();
});

it('should be accessible in app module', function () {
    expect(app.pivotTableService).toNotBe(null); //this test runs fine
});

it('test decr...', inject(function ( pivotTableService) {
    ... //Fails here
..
..
```

**app.js**

```
  ..
    ..        
    angular.module('Konstrukt', ['ngGrid', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute','pasvaz.bindonce', 'ngAnimate', 'nvd3ChartDirectives', 'ui.select', 'ngProgress', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit','ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.cellNav', 'ui.grid.pinning', 'ui.grid.resizeColumns']);

          var app = angular.module('Konstrukt');
          app.config(function (STARTUP_CONFIG, BUDGETS, APPLICATIONS) {

        var STARTUP_CONFIG = STARTUP_CONFIG;
        var BUDGETS = BUDGETS;
        var APPLICATIONS = APPLICATIONS;

      });
      ..
      ..
```

**index.html**

```
    ..
    ..

    <script>
  setTimeout(function(){
  window.deferredBootstrapper.bootstrap({
    element: window.document.body,
    module: 'Konstrukt',
    resolve: {
      STARTUP_CONFIG: ['$http', function ($http) {
        return $http.get('/scripts/_JSON/activeBudgets.JSON');
      }],
      BUDGETS: ['$http', function ($http) {
        return $http.get('/scripts/_JSON/activeBudgets.JSON');
      }],
      APPLICATIONS: ['$http', function ($http) {
        return $http.get('/scripts/_JSON/applications.JSON');
      }]
    }
  })
  } , 1500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deferredBootstrapper` will not run in your unit tests, which means the constants it normally adds to your module won't be available.

You can add a global `beforeEach` that provides mocked versions of them:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.constant('STARTUP_CONFIG', { something: 'something' });
    $provide.constant('BUDGETS', { something: 'something' });
    $provide.constant('APPLICATIONS', { something: 'something' });
  });
});
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks. As I am not using (and apparently cant) these constants at all in my tests, it worked right out of the box :=)